# access and sort a filtered data list from another component

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, payload

i have a filtered list 'accountList' that stores accounts information the list is fetched from the backend the payload looks like this
[payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0JmL.png)

the table is paginated and filtered the serives looks like that

```
  getAllFilteredAndSortedAccounts({ page, perPage, sortField, sortDir, filter }): Observable<AccountPaginationResponse> {
    let queryString = `${environment.apiUrl}/accounts?page=${page + 1}&perPage=${perPage}`;
    if (sortField && sortDir) {
      queryString = `${queryString}&sortField=${sortField}&sortDir=${sortDir}`;
    }
    if (filter) {
      queryString = `${queryString}&filter=${filter}`;
    }
    return this.http.get<AccountPaginationResponse>(queryString);
  }
```

on the account component the data is loaded as follow

```
  private loadAllAccounts() {
    return this.accountService.getAllFilteredAndSortedAccounts({
      page: this.paginator.pageIndex,
      perPage: this.paginator.pageSize,
      sortField: this.sort.active,
      sortDir: this.sort.direction,
      filter: ''
    })
     .subscribe(data => {
       this.dataSource.data = data.docs;
       this.allAccounts = data.docs;
       this.resultsLength = data.total;
    });
  }
```

so now i want to access the accountList from another component let says journal component and sort the table on a column like this:
*this is my attempts:*

```
  accountList: ChartOfAccounts[] = [];

  allAccountsSorted() {
    this.accountList.sort((x, y) => {
      if (x.accountName < y.accountName) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (x.accountName > y.accountName) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });

    return this.accountList;
  }
```

but in this case the accountList is undifined because it cannot be reached by using this.accountList.

[***check the payload***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0JmL.png)

```
  docs: Accounts[];
  total: number;
  pages: number;
  page: number;
  limit: number;
```

**my question is how can i access the docs list from another component and sort the data on a accountName?**

Comment: its not very clear what you mean here "but in this case the accountList data is contained under the docs list and sort is logically undefined". can you add more details?

Comment: i added the payload image to the post you can click on it to see what it looks like

Comment: Are you asking about passing data from one component to another? There are multiple options for that either through input output or via service.

Comment: @AnandBhushan i need to render the allAccountsSorted() on another component, could you provide a small example on how that work?

Comment: put your method allAccountsSorted() in a service, and that can be accessed from various components.